Can not access storage credential in Databricks due to missing permissions and workspace access
I have setup Unity Catalog and have a storage credential that I can not access.
In the storage credential section I accedential unchecked the "All workspace have access" checkbox.
I had not given any Permissions grants on the storage credential.
The problem now is that when I go to the storage credential I get the message
"Users cannot access the selected storage credential from this workspace.
Use the below screen to configure which workspaces are allowed to access the storage credential."
But there is no changes that can be done on the screen.
When I run SHOW STORAGE CREDENTIALS I can not see the Storage Credentials.
But in the portal it is visible. I am admin in the workspace.
I have managed to replicate this. Even if I am owner of the external storage I get the same issue. Seems to be a bug in the Databricks portal and that there is parts below the second screenshot that is missing?
I am workspace admin and metastore admin.
Is it possible to retreive access to the storage credential?



I was able to resolve this issue with this api command which basically restores the "All workspace have access" check:
curl  -X PATCH 
'https://workspace-url.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.1/unity-catalog/' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer bearer-token' 
--data-raw '{
"isolation_mode": "ISOLATION_MODE_OPEN"
}'
NB: remember to update the workspace url and bearer token
More information can be found here: Databricks Storage Credentials
